# Eliminar e inserir outro valor numa matriz em Python

Tags: python

Minha duvida é o seguinte: preciso que o usuário alimente uma matriz 3x3, e que ao digitar um valor do tipo inteiro, caso ele já exista nessa matriz, o programa deve informar que esse valor ja foi digitado e solicitar que seja inserido outro valor.

Estou usando esse procedimento para o usuário inserir os valores:

```
dados = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
dados_chk = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

# Inserção de dados pelo usuario
for linha in range (0,3):
    for coluna in range(0,3):
        dados_chk[linha][coluna]=int(input(f"Digite um valor para a posicao[{linha},{coluna}]: "))
        if dados_chk not in dados:
```

OBS: não sei se o que estou tentando fazer logo após a inserção do usuario faz sentido

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Primeiro, acho que seria mais fácil usar um `while` ao invés de `for`. Assim, você não fica preso ao tamanho da matriz. Na sua versão atual, se o usuário errar 9 vezes o loop termina com a matriz zerada.

Na minha opinião, você não precisa criar duas matrizes, uma apenas basta. O valor digitado pelo usuário pode ser armazenado em uma variável do tipo inteiro e depois conferido linha a linha da matriz. Então, se o valor digitado não existir na matriz basta inseri-lo na posição correta e incrementar um contador, não precisa remover e o código para isso você já tem. Se o valor já existir, não faça nada e retorne ao início do loop.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo....ja mexi aki e nada